# HTML/JS design - Slider Bar

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a slider like this:
[image]

I have based on this code but I can not get it to work when I have to convert it to a file. html.

http://shoutkey.com/sleeve

I am very new in thw world of web design.Thank you

Comment: First read the help center [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then ask a correct and specific question. We don't provide a "make my work" service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this below code and also link working fiddle link here you can take code and make file.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/iqbalp95/tsq2knxy/1/)

```js
$('.dot:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
  $('.inside').animate({
    'width': '20%'
  }, 500);
});
$('.dot:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
  $('.inside').animate({
    'width': '40%'
  }, 500);
});
$('.dot:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
  $('.inside').animate({
    'width': '60%'
  }, 500);
});
$('.dot:nth-child(4)').click(function() {
  $('.inside').animate({
    'width': '80%'
  }, 500);
});
if ($('#switch1').not(':checked')) {
  $('.modal').wrap('<div class="mask"></div>')
  $('.mask').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
    $('.mask article').animate({
      'top': '-100%'
    }, 300)
  });

  $('.dot').click(function() {
    var modal = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.mask').has('article.' + modal).fadeIn(300);
    $('.mask article.' + modal).fadeIn(0).animate({
      'top': '10%'
    }, 300);
  });
}
$("#switch1").click(function() {
  if ($('#switch1').is(':checked')) {
    $('.modal').unwrap('<div class="mask"></div>');
    $('.modal').hide();
    $('.modal').addClass('nobox');
    $('.dot').click(function() {
      var modal = $(this).attr('id');
      $('article.nobox').hide()
      $('article.nobox.' + modal).fadeIn(200)
    });
  } else {
    $('article').removeClass("nobox");
    $('.modal').wrap('<div class="mask"></div>')
    $('.mask').click(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(300);
      $('.mask article').animate({
        'top': '-100%'
      }, 300)
    });

    $('.dot').click(function() {
      var modal = $(this).attr('id');
      $('.mask').has('article.' + modal).fadeIn(300);
      $('.mask article.' + modal).fadeIn(0).animate({
        'top': '10%'
      }, 300);
    });
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

.checkcaption {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.check {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border: #222 solid 2px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.check input {
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
}
.check label {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: 12%;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.check input:checked + label {
  left: 55%;
  background-color: #7b3;
}

div#timeline {
  background-color: #6ab0de;
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
div#timeline .inside {
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 0%;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0;
}
div#timeline .dot {
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div#timeline .dot:nth-child(1) {
  left: 20%;
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}
div#timeline .dot:nth-child(2) {
  left: 40%;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}
div#timeline .dot:nth-child(3) {
  left: 60%;
  background-color: #7b3;
}
div#timeline .dot:nth-child(4) {
  left: 80%;
  background-color: #20638f;
}
div#timeline .dot:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
          transform: scale(1.2);
}
div#timeline .dot date {
  font-family: roboto;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  text-align: center;
}
div#timeline .dot span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

article {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  max-width: 960px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}
article date {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
article h2 {
  font-family: merriweather, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid #111 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
article p {
  line-height: 130%;
}

div.mask {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 99999;
}
div.mask article {
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 960px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
div.mask article date {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
div.mask article h2 {
  font-family: merriweather, sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: solid #111 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.mask article p {
  line-height: 130%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="checkcaption">no modal boxes?</p>
<div class="check">
 <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
 <label for="switch1"></label>
</div>

<div id="timeline">
 <div class="dot" id="one">
  <span></span>
  <date>1280</date>
 </div>
  <div class="dot" id="two">
  <span></span>
  <date>1649</date>
 </div>
  <div class="dot" id="three">
  <span></span>
  <date>1831</date>
 </div>
  <div class="dot" id="four">
  <span></span>
  <date>1992</date>
 </div>
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>

<!-- Modals -->

<article class='modal one'>
  <date>26/06 - 1280</date>
  <h2>Yo les gars</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates magnam excepturi laboriosam minima soluta, quae. Sunt repellat totam non, et sed in veniam fuga odio eius! Nesciunt amet optio recusandae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum sit dolor sint amet, corporis aperiam nihil, quas, accusantium enim suscipit rem non possimus officiis. Recusandae hic at, fugiat eos eveniet.</p>
</article>

<article class='modal two'>
  <date>08/09 - 1649</date>
  <h2>Salut les louzeurs</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates magnam excepturi laboriosam minima soluta, quae. Sunt repellat totam non, et sed in veniam fuga odio eius! Nesciunt amet optio recusandae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum sit dolor sint amet, corporis aperiam nihil, quas, accusantium enim suscipit rem non possimus officiis. Recusandae hic at, fugiat eos eveniet.</p>
</article>

<article class='modal three'>
  <date>21/07 - 1831</date>
  <h2>Eat 'em all !</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates magnam excepturi laboriosam minima soluta, quae. Sunt repellat totam non, et sed in veniam fuga odio eius! Nesciunt amet optio recusandae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum sit dolor sint amet, corporis aperiam nihil, quas, accusantium enim suscipit rem non possimus officiis. Recusandae hic at, fugiat eos eveniet.</p>
</article>

<article class='modal four'>
  <date>03/02 - 1992</date>
  <h2>Mais pourquoi?</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates magnam excepturi laboriosam minima soluta, quae. Sunt repellat totam non, et sed in veniam fuga odio eius! Nesciunt amet optio recusandae? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum sit dolor sint amet, corporis aperiam nihil, quas, accusantium enim suscipit rem non possimus officiis. Recusandae hic at, fugiat eos eveniet.</p>
</article>
```